# (Concept checking)Testing for diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the matrix $A \in M_{n \times n}(R)$, test A for diagonalizability.

$A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

> Question: To test for diagonalizability, is it true that as long as we can find distinct eigenvalues, which in this case, 3, then we look for three eigenspaces that together form a eigenbasis. If in this case, we can find three linearly independent eigenvectors that that such an eigenbasis, then we can say A is diagonalizable?

Comment: To each eigenvalue you are guaranteed at least one eigenvector. Eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are guaranteed to be linearly independent. Therefore if you have three distinct eigenvalues, the matrix _must_ be diagonalisable (you don’t even need to find the eigenvectors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix is diagonalizable if and only if there exist three linearly independent eigenvectors. However, you may not have to *find* them in order to guarantee that the matrix is diagonalizable, and you may not need to prove there are no such three vectors to prove it is not diagonalizable.

For example, a $3\times 3$ matrix that has three *distinct* eigenvalues is *always* diagonalizable (more generally, an $n\times n$ matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues is always diagonalizable). Because each eigenvalue has *at least* one eigenvector, and eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.

If the characteristic polynomial of the matrix does not split, then the matrix is **not** diagonalizable.

If the matrix has repeated eigenvalues, then you just need to check the eigenvalues with multiplicity greater than $1$: you need to verify there are at as many linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to *that* eigenvalue as the multiplicity (there’s always at least one).

For the matrix at hand, the characteristic polynomial is $-(t-1)(t^2+1)$. If you are working over $\mathbb{R}$, there aren’t enough eigenvalues, so it’s not diagonalizable. If you are working over $\mathbb{C}$, then the matrix has three *distinct* eigenvalues ($1$, $i$, and $-i$), so it **is** diagonalizable. No need to find any eigenvectors in this case.